# Android Compatibility Package doesn't include Activity.getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I started trying to add fragments to my Android app, which is based on 2.1, using the Android Compatibility Package that just came out on March 3rd.  I included the library into my project, and started moving the code from my Activity-based class to a Fragment-based one, but I noticed that the Fragment examples from Google seem to rely on the fact that the Activity class in 3.0 (Honeycomb) has the new method getFragmentManager().  It seems to be an integral hook into the Fragment system.

I've tried to look inside the Compatibility Package library for some included Activity implementation that has getFragmentManager(), but I can't find it.  Does anyone know where I can find getFragmentManager() so I can include Fragments for Honeycomb compatibility, or if not do you know how I can include Fragments without using a FragmentManager?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You will need to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of the normal `Activity`. Then you will be able to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` which works the same way as `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Any suggestions for using Google Maps API in this way?  Can't extend MapView and FragmentActivity at the same time

Comment: What is the difference between getSupportFragmentManager() and getFragmentmanager()?

Comment: @IgorG. getFragmentManager() is only available in Android 3.0+ and is the "native" method of getting the FragmentManager. getSupportFragmentManager() does basically the same thing, but it the compatibility library implementation of the method.

Comment: When developing an application that's deployed on 2.2 forward, does the "getSupportFragmentManager()" simply call "getFragmentManager()" on platforms that support the native call?

Answer (score 0):

You have only to change your Android Target to API Level = 12

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to make this work with Google Maps SDK see [getFragmentManager with API8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042459/getfragmentmanager-with-api8) and remember to update your layout file too!