# Fragment add or replace not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using the code from this [reference.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

When I put in that code in my program I get an error as seen in the picture below.
[image]

Any reasons for the error?
`The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, ExampleFragments)`

Code from my main activity:

```
public void red(View view) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ExampleFragments fragment = new ExampleFragments();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

ExampleFragments.java

```
package com.example.learn.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ExampleFragments extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blue_pill_frag, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here:

```
package com.example.learn.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Comment: Can you show your `ExampleFragments` class? I suspect it does not extend `Fragment`.

Comment: Updated my questions to show ExampleFragments.java

Comment: Why are you using `ExampleFragments fragment = new ExampleFragments();` and not `Fragment fragment = new Fragment()` ?

Comment: I copied and pasted from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
`You can then add a fragment using the add() method, specifying the fragment to add and the view in which to insert it. For example:`

Comment: just to clarify, in order to get rid of the errors, you have to make Android's sample FragmentLayout.java code's "DetailsActivity" extend "FragmentActivity" not "Activity," then Eric's solution will work.

Comment: You need to check the imports. import the version of Fragment which is needed in the replace() method. I was also facing same in Android Studio and its solved now.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The problem here is that you're mixing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment`. You need to convert all uses to use the support library, which also means calling `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Something like this, for example:

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ExampleFragments fragment = new ExampleFragments();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It is important to note that the support library `Fragment` and the normal `Fragment` are NOT interchangeable. They achieve the same purpose, but they cannot be replaced with one another in code.

Comment: Getting an error on `getSupportFragmentManager()` The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity. I'm updating my question to show imports.

Comment: Your activity needs to extend FragmentActivity, not Activity.

Comment: @Sam_D - Beat me to it. EGHDK - There is an explanation of that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209170/android-compatibility-package-doesnt-include-activity-getfragmentmanager).

Comment: So if the activity deals with fragments at all it "has" to extend fragment activity?

Comment: Yes, some form of `FragmentActivity`. There are extended classes, such as `ListFragmentActivity`, or `SherlockFragmentActivity` (if using ActionBarSherlock), but yes, all `Activity`s handling `Fragments` must extend some form of a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Awesome. Very insightful. I have one last question though, because the code works, but adds the layout and doesn't replace it. IE: The old layout in the fragment is still there. Should replace have taken care of that?

Comment: Yes, it should have. However, I would suggest marking a solution for this question and asking a new question for that, as sharing code gets to be rather cumbersome in comment streams. You may also find your solution in other `Fragment` or `.replace()` threads.

Comment: Thanks. I will start another question because I feel like I am executing the solution to my problem the wrong way. Thanks

Comment: Here is my new question. Thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620855/replacing-fragments-isnt-working-am-i-executing-this-the-proper-way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14307/discussion-between-eghdk-and-eric)

Comment: Ensure that ExampleFragments class also imports android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and not android.support.app.Fragment;

Comment: Eric help me.I am getting a weird problem.`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443583/comiple-errorthe-method-replace-in-the-type-fragmenttransaction-is-not-applicab`.please check out and tell me the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I spent a week on this issue. This works for me.

Comment: Hi initial fragment replacement is working but while second time replacing same fragment getting null pointer error please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Although this question may have been answered, it should be noted that the solution to overlapping fragments is to get the fragment ID (actually the FrameLayout id as declaring  in your xml will lead to headaches) with a fresh "Fragment" instance:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new ExampleFragments();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I can't tell you how many hours I spent going through post after post with no solution.  I read your other post that's linked in the comments above and I'm going to answer there as well just in case someone finds that first.

For those who are getting a `ClassCastException`, try this as well.  You can have all the right libraries added, using `FragmentActivity` instead of `Fragment`, and have getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager in your code to stop errors in a ListFragment and you'll still run into problems with Fragments.  Google docs don't show you everything, and Eclipse code completion will not always save you...sometimes you just have to fix the bug yourself!!

Comment: "(actually the FrameLayout id as declaring in your xml will lead to headaches) " saved me

Answer (score 0):

No matter what I tried (including the ones written here), I could not solve this issue until I saw this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5907704/728312

Answer (score 0):

Thisworked for me

`android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag, new ExampleFragments()).commit();
```