# Fragment add is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here is my main:

```
package com.example.frags;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


public class NewMessage extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_message);

        //Set new fragment
        FragA fragA = new FragA();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container_id, fragA);
        transaction.commit();

    }


}
```

My FragA class:

```
package com.example.frags;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.style.SuperscriptSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragA extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_pill_frag, container, false);
    }
}
```

This problem is very similar to a problem I had a [few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619573/fragment-add-or-replace-not-working), but I'm applying that solution to this application and I still can't get it to work.

I'm getting a red line under `.add` with the message saying `The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, fragA)`

This is aggravating because in another sample application I have [this code](http://pastebin.com/AVRCa8G9) written. Which looks identical, but it works!

Comment: Post your `FragA` class, I'd bet you forgot to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619573/fragment-add-or-replace-not-working
Heres your solution! Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm... I just did a clean, deleted my R.java and restarted eclipse. And now it works. Oh boy.

Comment: You've gotta love eclipse (she says sarcastically). I hope by now (almost 2 years later) you've switched to beautiful Android Studio :)