# How to attach SlidingMenu to ordinary Activity(not FragmentActivity) and make fragment replace work?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity which must extends from another activity, so i cannot embed the SlidingMenu at the Activity level. from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu i learned that i should call `SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(Activity activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW | SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT)`. Besides that, i want to replace listView to my customed ListFragment, that is:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SampleListFragment())
.commit();
```

But since my activity is not a subclass of **FragmentActivity**, so `getSupportFragmentManager()` would failed. And `getFragmentManager()` doesn't work too. Here are the details: [Fragment add or replace not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619573/fragment-add-or-replace-not-working). So, in short, i want attach a sliding menu to my activity, and i want the replace call success too, how can i achieve that?

Comment: AFAIK,you need to extend `FragmentActivity` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

please pay attention to this:
[see the last section "Using the fly-in app menu between Activities"](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/06/08/the-making-of-prixing-3-polishing-the-sliding-app-menu/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

It's official Android Navigation Drawer. You don't need 3rd party libraries now.