# How to Pass ArrayList from Activity to Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, fragmenttransaction

I have a MainActivity and a fragment. What I want to do is pass array list from my main activity to my fragment.

In my MainActivity my code looks like this:

```
private final List<RestaurantParcelableModel> restaurantList = new ArrayList<>();
...
RestaurantsFragment restaurantsFragment = new RestaurantsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("restaurantList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) restaurantList);
        restaurantsFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.restaurants_list, restaurantsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Right now I am getting this error in fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.restaurants_list, ***restaurantsFragment***); - "*Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.test.restaurants.sliderfragments.RestaurantsFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'
replace     (int,   android.app.Fragment)   in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied 
to  (int,   com.test.restaurants.sliderfragments.RestaurantsFragment)*"

Comment: Is your `RestaurantsFragment` extending `Fragment` correctly?

Comment: Also be sure that `RestaurantParcelableModel` implements `Parcelable`. Because such type of casting - `(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) restaurantList ` is quiet danger.

Comment: both the Fragments using import `android.app.Fragment#` ??

Comment: Your fragment have to extend `android.app.Fragment` not a 
`android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in this particular case

Comment: @Sanoop import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Then use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment add or replace not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619573/fragment-add-or-replace-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now to fix the issue you have to handle your imports.

Either use `import android.app.Fragment` instead of `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Or Update the main content of your app with a support Fragment manager like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager().
```

But then you also have to change the type of the FragmentManager itself; `import android.app.FragmentManager` to `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: @Kemo Hope it helped :)

Comment: It did :) thank you Sanoop. I used import android.app.Fragment instead of import android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: I also tried using getSupprotFragmentManager(), but I got this error: "Cannot resolve symbol FragmentTransaction" in my code: `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.restaurantss_list, restaurantsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: Change those imports also.. @Kemo For Transaction

Comment: I did, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`, but it is showing as "unused import statement"

Comment: use this android.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: `import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124525/discussion-between-sanoop-and-kemo).

Answer (score 2):

@Kemo the same error i was facing now I used fragment support manager instead of fragment manager.Now its working fine.

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.ll, blankFragment, "");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your class RestaurantParcelableModel does not implements the Parceable class. Implement parceable class and override the required methods.

Visit: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Bundle` to send your ArrayList:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putStringArrayList("array", mArrayList);
restaurantsFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete line: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
and change it for `import android.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use parceable or serializabale to pass the object of arraylist
or array list.You can find the example of parceable from the givenlink of github.
[ParceableSample.zip download the zip file](https://github.com/penzebra123/MVP-Demo/blob/master/ParcelableSample.zip)

You can use the above link sample for passing the Array list or Object of array list.