# getFragmentManager with API8

Tags: android, fragment

I build my app with API17 as target and minSDK 12
now I have to make the app works on andorid.2.2 (API8) devices I chang the minSDK to 8 and the target SDK to 8 also I fix some errors but I don't know how to fix this

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

(error : getFragmentManager() is undefined )
how to use google map v2 
I added these to the Activity

```
import android.support.v4.app.* ;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

what else should I do to fix  this ??

Comment: you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` also extend `FragmentActivity` instead of Activity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You class must extend  `FragmentActivity`. Make sure you have added support library.

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Also in your xml

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also make sure you have imported

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

you need `getSupportFragmentManager()` as described in [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29)